# timedatectl- NTP Sync cannot set to yes

Tags: 16.04, time, realtime

I tried so much different things of installing ntpq or other stuff but nothing works.

I dont can change it to yes.
I hope someone can help here.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 
This is my terminal output of the Command timedatectl

```
      Local time: Tue 2017-06-27 20:52:45 CEST
  Universal time: Tue 2017-06-27 18:52:45 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Also tried this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04

But when i make `sudo timedatectl set-ntp on` it only changes Network time on: yes/no.

Also installed ntp. But from the command `sudo ntpq -p` i get this error

```
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

Comment: It seems `ntpd` is not started after installation. Try running `sudo ntpd -n` to see if it starts running and the configuration file is OK (option `-n` means not to fork  and to log to the calling terminal).

Comment: Addition: There is nothing wrong with the output of `timedatectl`. If `ntpd`is not installed, `NTP synchronized: no` is OK (see https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html#timesyncd)

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox Guest Additions installed?

Answer (score 31):

When the clock is too much desincronized (more than 3 seconds?) it won't get update automatically.
In order to force it manually:

`sudo service ntp stop`
`sudo ntpd -gq`     ← here you can see it's getting sync
`sudo service ntp start`

Confirm everything's ok
`timedatectl`
Better explanation and all the credit [here](https://www.tecklyfe.com/fix-ubuntu-timedatectl-ntp-sync-no/)

Comment: Yes !!! Finally a working solution. I'm on ubuntu 18.04 (ubuntu-minimal)

Comment: this worked for raspbian stretch for rpi2 too! thanks

Comment: Worked for Raspberry pi 3 with stretch too.

Comment: for my install of 18.04 there is no ntp and should not be. What worked was simply to restart the service `sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd`

Answer (score 7):

After installing ntp

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

in the output of `timedatectl`

```
NTP synchronized: yes
```

the time is immediately automatically synchronized.

Comment: I still had to reboot after installing ntp

Comment: following this for 18.04 and beyond is a bad idea things have changed.  see my comment above to restart the systemd service