# I manually changed the time in the GUI. Now, my system clock is not synchronized. How can I fix this?

Tags: sync, time, timezone

As the title says, my system clock is not synchronized. This is problematic since I need to update my software, and I continue to receive errors such as "Release file ... is not valid yet." I have [tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid) [multiple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058593/how-to-sync-the-time-to-network-with-timedatectl-on-ubuntu-18-04) [fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929805/timedatectl-ntp-sync-cannot-set-to-yes) throughout this website but none have resolved my issue. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Some additional information:

- I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (no Windows in dualboot).
- When I run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd`,I get `Failed to restart systemd-timesyncd.service: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.`
- When I run `timedatectl`, I get

  ```
          Local time: Wed 2022-06-08 03:33:34 CDT
      Universal time: Wed 2022-06-08 08:33:34 UTC
            RTC time: Wed 2022-06-08 08:33:34
           Time zone: America/Chicago (CDT, -0500)
  ```

  System clock synchronized: no

  ```
         NTP service: n/a
     RTC in local TZ: no
  ```
- Also, because I tried some of those previous solutions, I lost the ability to automatically set date and time, as suggested by the first answer to this post.

Settings's GUI:

[image]

**UPDATES (thanks to user68186)**

1. I have the following in my `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file:

```
[Time] 
NTP=ntp.ubuntu.com 
FallbackNTP=pool.ntp.org       
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5 
#PollIntervalMinSec=32 
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

2. MY NTP service is now active again, and the "Automatic Date & Time" switch is once again available in my Settings GUI. This progress was made by referencing [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314479/ntp-not-supported), since NTP was not supported on my device.
3. I still am not having my time synchronized on my device.
4. Ran the following commands, which did not return errors!

`sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service`

`sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136950/discussion-on-question-by-mrschwob-i-manually-changed-the-time-in-the-gui-now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Command line steps (Work in progress)

First, unmask the service by:

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timesyncd
```

Then install the service again

```
sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd
```

Activate NTP:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

At this point your NTP service should be active again, and the "Automatic Date & Time" switch is once again available in your Settings GUI.

If that does not help, try these two commands again:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
```

I checked two of my computers both has the following lines in their `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`:

```
[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

From the `man timesyncd.conf` command:

> The default configuration is
> defined during compilation, so a configuration file is only needed
> when it is necessary to deviate from those defaults. By default, the
> configuration file in /etc/systemd/ contains commented out entries
> showing the defaults as a guide to the administrator. This file can be
> edited to create local overrides.

So, it seems editing this file was not needed.

Reboot the computer to make sure the services are initialized at boot time:

```
sudo reboot
```

After rebooot, check again:

```
timedatectl status
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I had that selected initially, and that didn't solve the issue. After going through several other solutions (the linked posts in the answer), I lost access to that option altogether. See the attached picture in the post for evidence. Are there any other ideas you have?

Comment: Automatic time zone, date, and time are all enabled in the GUI

Comment: I swear I restarted it before that comment and received the same error. Just tried again, and now the time is synced. I cannot express enough how much I appreciate your help and patience. You have been so incredibly helpful. Note to everyone: do NOT manually change the time in the Settings GUI. Instead, just enable location services and let the computer automatically update everything.